# automating LIMS data entry

Tags: powershell, ms-word, data-entry

I begin to work as a stagiaire in a pharmaceutical company, they expect to me that I will read the Master Batch Records, that is the detailed recipes of their drugs, and that I will put the parts regarding the "in process controls" in their LIMS (Laboratory Information Management System) in order have a better control of the production process.

It is a quite boring task that requires also a lot of attention since their LIMS is quite counterintuitive and old.

I would like to know your opinion about my naive opinions/thoughts:

I thought that the company needs could be satisfied if they somehow convert their master batch records (they are WORD files) in something like web sites in which the worker can write his/her analysis/controls, so my questions:

- could it be possible to dismiss that LIMS in this way?
- Also considering that they own a SAP system, why did they need to add a LIMS that has already shown some problems in its interface with SAP?

Maybe, since they spent a lot of money in validating that software, it might be useful somehow:

- could it be possible to extract the necessary information from the MBR files and convert it in something LIMS can understand, in order to automate the work I should do?
- I mean is it possible at least in principle? With Powershell scripting?

Comment: Are they by chance looking for a new system or need some help with this project?  I'm the lead developer for a software company that sells their LIMS system for drug testing in a laboratory.  I've done quite a bit of automation for them.  If interested, reply back and I can get you my contact info.

Answer (score 0):

Mareczek, I do use AutoHotKey to read data from excel into an array in memory. AutoHotKey then switches to the SAP GUI to automatically enter the data for me.
What it does at every step is to verify that the right window is open and that the entered data was accepted. If this could help you, let me know. I can send some sample scripts. Regards,

Robert Ilbrink

Comment: thank you Robert I really appreciate your kindness, I would be glad to study your scripts so that I could start learning to script in a windows environment

Comment: Mareczek, contact me via email (firstname dot lastname at gmail dot com) and I'll send you some example scripts. Regards,

Comment: Mareczek, You might have tried contacting me, be aware that my last name is ilbrink, when I write the first i as capital, it looks the same as the L following the i.